# PHP else statement not working when sequencing

Tags: php, wordpress, if-statement

So a little background on what I'm trying to do here. For this project I'm working with someone's else's API calls in Wordpress, and basically if your search brings up nothing display a error saying no content found.

I did not write most of the PHP and API calls but I put the HTML around it all. I'm having a hard time figuring this one out. I would think at the bottom I can add the else statement and it should work but it's not.

Code is long so here is a link to it, hoping someone with a little more PHP knowledge can help me out here, at the very bottom you can see my else statement.

```
<?php /*
        Template Name: Search Results
      */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content">
    <header class="article-header">
        <div class="row small-12 columns">
            <h1 class="page-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        </div>
    </header> <!-- end article header -->
    <div id="inner-content" class="row">
        <main id="main" class="large-8 medium-8 columns search-results" role="main">
            <h2>
                <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                    Search Results for:
                <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                    Buscar resultados para:
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php $searchResultFor = '';
                if ((isset($_POST['API_Method']) && $_POST['API_Method'] != '') || (isset($_SESSION['API_Method']) && $_SESSION['API_Method'] != '')) {
                    $_SESSION['API_Method'] = $_POST['API_Method'];
                    $_SESSION['ZipCode'] = $_POST['ZipCode'];
                    $methodToCall = $_POST['API_Method'];
                    $ZipCode = $_POST['ZipCode'];
                    $County = $_POST['County'];
                    $State = $_POST['State'];
                    $AddressLine1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
                    $City = $_POST['City'];
                    $StateAbbr = $_POST['StateAbbr'];
                    $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
                    if ($methodToCall == 'ProviderSearchByZip') {
                        $ZipCode = $_POST['ZipCode'];
                        $searchResultFor = $ZipCode;
                    }
                    if ($methodToCall == 'ProviderSearchByCounty') {
                        $County = $_POST['County'];
                        $State = $_POST['State'];
                        $searchResultFor = $County . ' ' . $State;
                    }
                    if ($methodToCall == 'ProviderSearchByCity') {
                        $City = $_POST['City'];
                        $State = $_POST['State'];
                        $searchResultFor = $City . ' ' . $State;
                    }
                    if ($methodToCall == 'ProviderSearchByAddress') {
                        $AddressLine1 = $_POST['AddressLine1'];
                        $City = $_POST['City'];
                        $StateAbbr = $_POST['StateAbbr'];
                        $Zip = $_POST['Zip'];
                        $searchResultFor = $AddressLine1 . ' ' . $City . ' ' . $StateAbbr . ' ' . $Zip;
                    }
                }
                echo $searchResultFor;
                ?>
            </h2>
            <?php $methodToCall = '';
            $message = '';
            $objSearchData['Providers'] = array();
            if (isset($_POST['API_Method']) && $_POST['API_Method'] != '') {
                $methodToCall = $_POST['API_Method'];
                $objSearchData = get_search_result($methodToCall, $ZipCode, $nameid = '', $County, $State, $City, $address1, $StateAbbr, $Zip);
            }
            ?>
            <?php
            if (!empty($objSearchData['Providers'])) {
            // print_R($objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']);die;
            if (array_key_exists(0, $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider'])) {
                foreach ($objSearchData['Providers']['Provider'] as $k => $fdata) {
                    if ($k == 0) {
                        $add1 = $fdata['AddressLine1'];
                        $city = $fdata['City'];
                        $state = $fdata['StateProvinceCode'];
                        $postcode = $fdata['PostalCode'];
                        $address = $add1 . ", " . $city . ", " . $state . ", " . $postcode;
                        $nameid = $fdata['NameID'];
                        $orgname = $fdata['OrganizationName'];
                        $phone = $fdata['PhoneNumber'];
                        $tollfree = $fdata['Toll_Free'];
                        $fax = $fdata['FaxNumber'];
                        $email = $fdata['EmailAddress'];
                        $website = $fdata['WebSiteAddress'];
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } else {
                $add1 = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['AddressLine1'];
                $city = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['City'];
                $state = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['StateProvinceCode'];
                $postcode = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['PostalCode'];
                $address = $add1 . ", " . $city . ", " . $state . ", " . $postcode;
                $nameid = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['NameID'];
                $orgname = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['OrganizationName'];
                $phone = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['PhoneNumber'];
                $tollfree = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['Toll_Free'];
                $fax = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['FaxNumber'];
                $email = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['EmailAddress'];
                $website = $objSearchData['Providers']['Provider']['WebSiteAddress'];
            }
            ?>
            <?php $methodToCall_1 = 'GetProviderDetails';
            $objSearchData_1 = get_search_result($methodToCall_1, $ZipCode, $nameid, $County, $State, $City, $address1, $StateAbbr, $Zip);
            ?>
            <div class="row search-holder">
                <div class="small-12 columns">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rutrum odio imperdiet purus
                        pulvinar, a ultrices tellus mattis. Vestibulum nec ligula commodo, commodo ipsum sed, placerat
                        magna. Pellentesque rutrum nulla nec iaculis volutpat. Pellentesque pellentesque sit amet ante a
                        elementum. Nunc bibendum sodales vulputate.</p>
                    <h3><a href="<?php echo get_permalink('262') . '?id=' . $nameid ?>"><?php echo $orgname; ?></a></h3>
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-7 columns">
                            <p><?php echo $add1; ?><br/><?php echo $city; ?>, <?php echo $state; ?>
                                , <?php echo $postcode; ?></p>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <p><span>Phone: </span><?php echo ($phone != '') ? $phone : "Not available"; ?></p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <p><span>Teléfono: </span><?php echo ($phone != '') ? $phone : "Not available"; ?></p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <p>
                                    <span>Toll Free: </span><?php echo ($tollfree != '') ? $tollfree : "Not available"; ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <p><span>Gratuito: </span><?php echo ($tollfree != '') ? $tollfree : "Not available"; ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <p><span>Fax: </span><?php echo ($fax != '') ? $fax : "Not available"; ?></p>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <p>
                                    <span>Toll Free: </span><?php echo ($tollfree != '') ? $tollfree : "Not available"; ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <p><span>Gratuito: </span><?php echo ($tollfree != '') ? $tollfree : "Not available"; ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <p><span>Email: </span><?php if ($email != "") { ?>
                                        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <?php echo "Not available"; ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <p><span>Correo Electrónico: </span><?php if ($email != "") { ?>
                                        <a href="mailto:<?php echo $email; ?>" target="_blank"><?php echo $email; ?></a>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <?php echo "Not available"; ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <p class="search_website">
                                    <?php if ($website != "") { ?>
                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $website; ?>" target="_blank">Website</a>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <?php echo "Not available"; ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <p class="search_website">
                                    <?php if ($website != "") { ?>
                                        <a href="http://<?php echo $website; ?>" target="_blank">Página de Internet</a>
                                    <?php } else { ?>
                                        <?php echo "Not available"; ?>
                                    <?php } ?>
                                </p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- end columns -->
                        <div class="small-12 medium-5 columns">
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <h4>Hours Of Operation</h4>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <h4>Horas de Operación</h4>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($objSearchData_1['Provider']['HoursOfOperation'])) {
                                $HoursOfOperation = $objSearchData_1['Provider']['HoursOfOperation']['DayTime'];
                                $HoursOfOperationcount = count($HoursOfOperation);
                                for ($y = 0; $y < $HoursOfOperationcount; $y++) {
                                    $starttime24 = $HoursOfOperation[$y]['StartTime'];
                                    $starttime12 = date("g:i a", strtotime($starttime24));

                                    $endtime24 = $HoursOfOperation[$y]['EndTime'];
                                    $endtime12 = date("g:i a", strtotime($endtime24));
                                    echo ' <p><span>' . $HoursOfOperation[$y]['DayOfWeek'] . '</span>' . ' ' . $starttime12 . ' to ' . $endtime12 . '</p>';
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div><!-- end columns -->
                    </div><!-- end row -->
                    <div class="row ccrr">
                        <div class="small-12 medium-9 columns">
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <h2>Access Your CCR&R's Online Child Care Search</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rutrum odio imperdiet
                                    purus pulvinar, a ultrices tellus mattis. Vestibulum nec ligula commodo, commodo
                                    ipsum sed, placerat magna.</p>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <h2>Buscar el cuidado de niños en línea por su agencia local</h2>
                                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc rutrum odio imperdiet
                                    purus pulvinar, a ultrices tellus mattis. Vestibulum nec ligula commodo, commodo
                                    ipsum sed, placerat magna.</p>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- end columns -->
                        <div class="small-12 medium-3 columns">
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $objSearchData_1['Provider']['FindChildCareNow']; ?>"
                                   class="button standard small" title="Link-State-by-State-Resources">Learn More</a>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <a href="<?php echo $objSearchData_1['Provider']['FindChildCareNow']; ?>"
                                   class="button standard small" title="Link-State-by-State-Resources">Aprende más</a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        </div><!-- end columns -->
                    </div><!-- end ccrr -->
                </div><!-- end columns -->
            </div><!-- end search-holder -->
            <div class="row small-12 columns">
                <?php if (!empty($objSearchData_1['Provider']['Counties'])) { ?>
                    <ul class="accordion ask" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
                        <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                            <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                                <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Areas Served</a>
                            <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                                <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Condados Servidos</a>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content><?php
                                if (strpos($objSearchData_1['Provider']['Counties'], ',')) {
                                    $exp_con = explode(',', $objSearchData_1['Provider']['Counties']);

                                    $newstring = join(', ', $exp_con);
                                    $newstring = rtrim($newstring, ",");
                                } elseif ($objSearchData_1['Provider']['Counties'] != '') {
                                    $newstring = $objSearchData_1['Provider']['Counties'];
                                }
                                echo $newstring;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- end row columns -->
            <div class="row small-12 columns">
                <ul class="accordion ask" data-accordion data-allow-all-closed="true">
                    <li class="accordion-item" data-accordion-item>
                        <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                            <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Services Offered</a>
                        <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                            <a href="#" class="accordion-title">Servicios Ofrecidos</a>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="accordion-content" data-tab-content>
                            <?php
                            if (!empty($objSearchData_1['Provider']['Services']['Service'])) {
                                $Service = $objSearchData_1['Provider']['Services']['Service'];
                                echo ' <ul> ';
                                $Servicecount = count($Service);
                                if ($Servicecount == 1) {
                                    echo '<li>' . $Service . '</li>';
                                } else {
                                    for ($y = 0; $y < $Servicecount; $y++) {
                                        echo '<li>' . $Service[$y] . '</li>';
                                    }
                                }
                                echo '</ul>';
                            } else {
                                echo ' No services offered at this location';
                            }
                            ?>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- end row columns -->
            <div class="state-links">
                <?php if (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'en'): ?>
                    <h2>State Resources</h2>
                <?php elseif (ICL_LANGUAGE_CODE == 'es'): ?>
                    <h2>Recursos Estatales Útiles</h2>
                <?php endif; ?>
                <?php
                $stateArray = array(
                    'AL' => 'Alabama',
                    'AK' => 'Alaska',
                    'AZ' => 'Arizona',
                    'AR' => 'Arkansas',
                    'CA' => 'California',
                    'CO' => 'Colorado',
                    'CT' => 'Connecticut',
                    'DE' => 'Delaware',
                    'DC' => 'District of Columbia',
                    'FL' => 'Florida',
                    'GA' => 'Georgia',
                    'HI' => 'Hawaii',
                    'ID' => 'Idaho',
                    'IL' => 'Illinois',
                    'IN' => 'Indiana',
                    'IA' => 'Iowa',
                    'KS' => 'Kansas',
                    'KY' => 'Kentucky',
                    'LA' => 'Louisiana',
                    'ME' => 'Maine',
                    'MD' => 'Maryland',
                    'MA' => 'Massachusetts',
                    'MI' => 'Michigan',
                    'MN' => 'Minnesota',
                    'MS' => 'Mississippi',
                    'MO' => 'Missouri',
                    'MT' => 'Montana',
                    'NE' => 'Nebraska',
                    'NV' => 'Nevada',
                    'NH' => 'New Hampshire',
                    'NJ' => 'New Jersey',
                    'NM' => 'New Mexico',
                    'NY' => 'New York',
                    'NC' => 'North Carolina',
                    'ND' => 'North Dakota',
                    'OH' => 'Ohio',
                    'OK' => 'Oklahoma',
                    'OR' => 'Oregon',
                    'PA' => 'Pennsylvania',
                    'RI' => 'Rhode Island',
                    'SC' => 'South Carolina',
                    'SD' => 'South Dakota',
                    'TN' => 'Tennessee',
                    'TX' => 'Texas',
                    'UT' => 'Utah',
                    'VT' => 'Vermont',
                    'VA' => 'Virginia',
                    'WA' => 'Washington',
                    'WV' => 'West Virginia',
                    'WI' => 'Wisconsin',
                    'WY' => 'Wyoming'
                );

                $args = array('post_type' => 'state', 'name' => $stateArray[$state]);
                $the_query = new WP_Query($args);
                if ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                    while ($the_query->have_posts()) :
                        $the_query->the_post();
                        if (have_rows('state_links')) :
                            ?>
                            <div class="row small-up-2 medium-up-3 large-up-3 state-links">
                                <?php
                                while (have_rows('state_links')) :
                                    the_row();
                                    if (have_rows('links')) :
                                        while (have_rows('links')) :
                                            the_row();
                                            $link_title = get_sub_field('link_title');
                                            $link_url = get_sub_field('link_url');
                                            $link_icon = get_sub_field('link_icon');
                                            ?>
                                            <div class="column link-content">
                                                <div class="link-holder">
                                                    <img
                                                        src="<?php echo get_bloginfo('template_directory'); ?><?= $link_icon ?>">
                                                    <a href="<?= $link_url ?>" target="_blank" class="button standard"
                                                       title=""><?= $link_title ?></a>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endwhile;
                                    endif;
                                endwhile;
                                ?>
                            </div>
                        <?php endif;
                    endwhile;
                endif;
                ?>
                <?php } else: { ?>

                    <h2>No Content Avalable</h2>

                <?php } ?>
            </div><!-- end state-links -->
        </main><!-- end #main -->
        <div id="sidebar1" class="sidebar large-4 medium-4 columns" role="complementary">
            <?php $sidebar = get_field('sidebar');
            dynamic_sidebar('global-top');
            dynamic_sidebar($sidebar);
            dynamic_sidebar('global-bottom');
            ?>
        </div>
    </div><!-- end inner-content -->
</div><!-- end content -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Please post a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) here, not just as a link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mix the two syntaxes within a block. We'd expect this code to return a syntax error.

Current code looks to be following this pattern:

```
            if (!empty($objSearchData['Providers'])) {     

            } else: {

            }
```

That colon following the else  (**`else:`**) isn't valid.

---

Just remove the colon after the else

```
            if (!empty($objSearchData['Providers'])) {

            } else {

            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else at the end of the file should like like this:

```
<?php else: ?>

    <h2>No Content Avalable</h2>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply but that was not it. If you replace my code at the end with '<?php } ?>' That is what was originally there when I first got the code and I added what i thought was right. Not sure if that will help in debugging this